# Auto height of table-row

Tags: css

In [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/gGpNw/) you can see 2 table-rows. I need the first one's height to be set automatically. Second one's height need to be set to the bottom of the page.
But the browser sets table row height as 50%...

```
.table {
    display: table;
    table-layout: auto;
}
html,body {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100% !important;
}

.row {
    display: table-row;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set `height:100%` on the second row.

```
<div class="row">
        <div>Some text</div>
        <div>Text again</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row last">
        <div>Need height to bottom</div>
    </div>
```

### CSS

```
.row {
    display: table-row;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.last
{
    height: 100%;
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/gGpNw/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

content which you want to show at bottom of the page apply this class to that division.

```
.row { 
    position: absolute; 
    bottom: 0; 
    left: 0; 
}
```

[Division at bottom side](http://jsfiddle.net/gGpNw/1/)

Comment: I do not want to see this content at a bottom. I want to set bottom row's height to mottom.

Comment: @GeorgyLiparteliani then add  height attribute to that class. like " height : 20%;"

Comment: Here in your jsfiddle two divisions are there in your body tag and also same style applies to both so automatically height is divided 100/2 = 50%

Answer (score 0):

Just Add these lines and you will get the required result:

```
<div class="last">
    <div>Need height to bottom</div>
</div>

.last
{
    height: 100%;
}
```